Difficulty in filtering products based on query parameter in React component
I am encountering an issue while attempting to filter products based on a query parameter in a React component. I have a Main component that fetches products from a context and extracts a query parameter from the URL using useLocation from react-router-dom. I then use useState and useEffect hooks to filter the products based on this query parameter.
The filtering logic seems correct, as I'm checking if the query parameter is undefined and, if so, setting FilteredProducts to the entire products array. However, despite this logic, the component is not displaying all products when query is undefined. While it is filtering the products for the categories but not showing the entire products when I visit on the '/' or route. Also whenever I refresh page in certain query (not undefined) it then show loading.
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Product from "./Product";
import { ProductContext } from "../utils/Context";
import Loading from "./Loading";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function Main() {
  const { products } = useContext(ProductContext);
  const { search } = useLocation();
  let query = decodeURIComponent(search.split("=")[1]);
  const [FilteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("component createed");
    if (products) {
      if (query) {
        setFilteredProducts(
          products.filter((product) => product.category == query)
        );
      } else {
        setFilteredProducts(products);
      }
    }
    
  }, [query]);

  return FilteredProducts.length == 0 ? (
    <Loading />
  ) : (
    <div className="w-[80%] px-5 py-28 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto">
      <div className="flex justify-center gap-4  flex-wrap">
        {FilteredProducts.map((product) => (
          <Product key={product.id} product={product} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Main;

I tried filtering products based on a query parameter in a React component. I expected the component to display all products when the query parameter is undefined, and to display filtered products when the query parameter is defined (which is working).

try using query in useState
const [query, setQuery] = useState("")

and set its value in useEffect
useEffect(()=>{
    setQuery(decodeURIComponent(search.split("=")[1]))
},[])


in this code you not mentioned where i have to put the filtering products logic

no need to change other code, keep them as it is

Still it is not working for me

Looks like you have not added products as dependency in useEffect hook.
Try adding the products as dependency in useEffect.
useEffect(() => {
   // remaining code
}, [query, products])


now its working only just for the categories not for the whole products

and also clarify why should i include the products in the array

The issue might be with let query = decodeURIComponent(search.split("=")[1]);, it doesn't get the correct value you are expecting, depending on what the search string value actually is. It also appears to assume only one search parameter is possible.
Take for example search string "?bar=bar&foo=foo", if foo was the query value you want to filter by, using search.split("=") yields ["?bar", "bar&foo", "foo"] and so the value at index 1, "bar&foo", would be used and likely would filter out all product data.


const search="?bar=bar&foo=foo";
console.log(search.split("=")[1]);



Additionally your useEffect hook is missing a dependency on the products array it filters over, so any updates to products won't be captured until the query dependency updates.
It would be better to create an actual URLSearchParams object and read the appropriate query parameter value. If there is no matching parameter in the search string then null is returned.
const { search } = useLocation(); // "?bar=bar&foo=foo"
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);

const bar = searchParams.get("bar"); // "bar"
const foo = searchParams.get("foo"); // "foo"
const foobar = searchParams.get("foobar"); // null

It is a general React anti-pattern to compute and store derived state into React state. Just compute and use the derived filter value directly in the component rendering it.
Example:
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Product from "./Product";
import { ProductContext } from "../utils/Context";
import Loading from "./Loading";

function Main() {
  const { products } = useContext(ProductContext);
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  // assumed parameter name, e.g. "...?...&category=foo&...", adjust/tweak
  // this to match your actual URL path + search
  const category = searchParams.get("category");

  const filteredProducts = products.filter(product => {
    return category ? product.category === category : true;
  });

  return filteredProducts.length ? (
    <div className="w-[80%] px-5 py-28 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto">
      <div className="flex justify-center gap-4  flex-wrap">
        {filteredProducts.map((product) => (
          <Product key={product.id} product={product} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : <Loading />;
}

export default Main;

In fact also, just about 100% of the time you see that you have coded a useState-useEffect pairing you should really be using the useMemo hook to compute and memoize a derived value.
const { products } = useContext(ProductContext);
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

const category = searchParams.get("category");

// Re-compute filtered products any time products array or
// query parameter values update.
const filteredProducts = React.useMemo(() => {
  return products.filter(product => {
    return category ? product.category === category : true;
  });
}, [products, category]);

